# pause transfer on filezilla and continue later (will shutdown my pc)

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I am using FileZilla to transfer my files from my PC to the FTP server. However, I want to upload a large queue which will take some time. I would like to know how to pause the transfer and complete it later. I want to shutdown my PC and continue the transfer after turning it on again.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To pause the transfer and complete it later:

First of all, before pausing make sure to go to the "Failed transfers" tab in the queue box and right click it then click "Reset and requeue all".

After that you've to go to the "Queued files" tab and right click the queue box then uncheck the box "Process Queue" - by that you've paused the transfer, you can close FileZilla and complete it later.

How to resume? Just right click the queue box again and check the box "Process Queue".